# Jetpack Compose - changing variable in a viewModel causes changes to the viewModel state?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I will describe my problem and then I'll provide my implementation.
I have a viewModel with a variable `connectionStatus` that stores the value that tracks the connectionStatus of a "device", and changes when the connection status of the device changes.

I display the conneciton status in a Text composable.
below the text cmposable, I also have a button "cancel connection", which calls the cancelConnection method in the viewModel.

**the problem:** every time the connection status is changing, the `conectionStatus` variable changes, which makes a recomposition for the Text composable (this is ok, expected behavior), but it also cause the button to be recomposed, even though nothing changed in the button state.

now, I think the problem is that the `connectionState` cause the state for the whole viewModel to be changed, because when I removed the Text composable, and left with only the button composable, it still was recomposed every time the `connectionStatus` was changed.

This is my implemntation:
**ViewModel:**

```
class ConnectableTopAppBarViewModel(
    private val connectControllerUseCase: ConnectControllerUseCase = ConnectControllerUseCase()
) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ConnectableTopAppBarUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<ConnectableTopAppBarUiState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private val _connectionStatus = mutableStateOf(ConnectionStatus.AWAIT_CONNECTION)
    val connectionStatus get() = _connectionStatus
    
    private var job = Job()
        get() {
            if (field.isCancelled) field = Job()
            return field
        }

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            connectControllerUseCase.getConnectionStatus().collect { newStatus ->
                _connectionStatus.value = newStatus
            }
        }
    }

    fun cancelConnection(deviceIp: String) {
        job.cancel()
        connectControllerUseCase.cancelConnection()
    }
}
```

**now in my composables I have sometihng like this:**

```
val connectionStatus by viewModel.connectionStatus
...
Text(text = connectionStatus)
...
CustomButton(cancelAction = viewModel::cancelConnection)
...
CustomButton(
    cancelAction = (String) -> ()
) {
    Button(onClick = { cancelAction("test") })
}
```

what am I missing here? why `CustomButton` is being recomposed every time the `connectionStatus` is changed? even though I'm passing method refference.

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to make _connectionStatus as MutableStateFlow. Can you try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
CustomButton(cancelAction = remember { viewModel::cancelConnection } )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?